# C++ tensorflow object detection datatype error

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am trying to modify the [examples/label_image main.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc) to export the trained model to C++. It seems the expected input type is uint8 (exact error: Running model failed: Invalid argument: Expects arg[0] to be uint8 but float is provided) . In the function ReadTensorFromImageFile() , I change the casting datatype to uint8, auto float_caster =      Cast(root.WithOpName("uint8_caster"), image_reader, tensorflow::DataType::DT_UINT8); but still the tensor returned is of type float? Is this a casting issue?

As, [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc)  says casting is supported for only few datatypes, is uint8 not supported? Am I looking at the right place for Cast() operator? Where is the function call to Cast() implemented?

Any tips to convert the C++ tensor to uint8 type?